# Finite integral domain is a field: proof condition

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, proof-explanation, finite-rings

> Theorem: a finite integral domain is a field

proof:

Let D be a finite integral domain with unity 1. Let a be any non-zero element of D.
If a=1, a is its own inverse and the proof concludes.

Suppose, then, a>1.
Since D is finite, the order of D is n. Then, $D =\left \{ e=0, a^{1},a^{2},\cdot \cdot \cdot a^{n-1} \right \}$.
Then, $\exists i,j \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}, i>j: a^{i}=a^{j}$

This implies $a^{i-j}=1$.

Now, I cannot understand the connection made from here(in bold):

Since $a\neq 1, i-j>1$. 
What does the fact that $a\neq 1$ has anything to do with i-j>1?

And we have shown that $a^{i-j-1}$ is the inverse of a.

Explanation is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any number other than $1$, the difference $(i - j)$ will be greater than 1. We can prove this by showing that:

Let $j - i = 1$. Hence,
$$
a^{(i - j)} = 1 \ \ \text{by assumption}\\ 
a^1 = 1 \\
a = 1
$$

So, If $a \neq 1$, $i - j > 1$ (since $i > j$ and $i - j \neq 1$)

Comment: This helps. Thank you.